gem install psych fails on Ruby 3.3.4
I need to have 2 versions of ruby installed for separate projects (2.6.6p146 and 3.3.4).
When I change ruby by using export PATH="...:/c/Ruby33-x64/bin:...", ruby -v reports 3.3.4.
However, gem install psych fails.
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (download library error)
ERROR:  Error installing psych:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/ext/psych
C:/Ruby33-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for pkg-config for yaml-0.1... not found
checking for yaml.h... no
yaml.h not found
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --without-opt-include
        --with-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --without-opt-lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby33-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-libyaml-source-dir
        --without-libyaml-source-dir
        --with-yaml-0.1-dir
        --without-yaml-0.1-dir
        --with-yaml-0.1-include=${yaml-0.1-dir}/include
        --without-yaml-0.1-include
        --with-yaml-0.1-lib=${yaml-0.1-dir}/lib
        --without-yaml-0.1-lib
        --with-yaml-0.1-config
        --without-yaml-0.1-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-libyaml-dir
        --without-libyaml-dir
        --with-libyaml-include=${libyaml-dir}/include
        --without-libyaml-include
        --with-libyaml-lib=${libyaml-dir}/lib
        --without-libyaml-lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/psych-5.2.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/psych-5.2.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/psych-5.2.0/gem_make.out
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libyaml
pacman failed with the following output:
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libyaml-0.2.5-2

Total Download Size:   0.08 MiB
Total Installed Size:  0.38 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
:: Retrieving packages...
 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libyaml-0.2.5-2-any downloading...
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
Building native extensions. This could take a while...

I've tried to compile psych from source, and tried uninstalling Ruby 2.6 temporarily. Even without Ruby 2.6, I still see the same error.
I'm using Git bash on Windows 11.

The solution was to download https://packages.msys2.org/packages/mingw-w64-x86_64-libyaml and install it manually by opening C:\Ruby33-x64\msys64\msys2 and running:
pacman -U /c/Users/burkipe/Downloads/mingw-w64-x86_64-libyaml-0.2.5-2-any.pkg.tar.zst
I then needed to specify the libyaml directory as so, in Git bash:
gem install psych -v 5.1.2 -- --with-libyaml-dir=/C/Ruby33-x64/msys64/mingw64/
